# Websockets/AngularJS data received from socket not binding into $scope variable

Tags: angularjs, websocket

I'm trying to get the data from a websocket using the function below

```
app.controller('Dashboard', ['$window', '$scope', '$http', function ($window, $scope, $http) {
    var url = new URL('/dashboard', window.location.href);
    url.protocol = url.protocol.replace('http', 'ws');
    var socket = new WebSocket(url.href);
    socket.onopen = function () {
        console.log("Status: Connected")
     };
    $scope.RX = function(event) {
        $scope.data = event.data 
        console.log(event.data)
    };
    socket.onmessage = $scope.RX;
    console.log($scope.data)
}]);
```

I assign the event.data to `$scope.data` inside the `RX` function, and I can check via `console.log(event.data)` that the data was properly received, however, if I check the value of `console.log($scope.data)` it comes undefined.

Seems like whatever I get in the RX function stays local... and I can't display it on my page using `{{data}}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [$scope.$apply](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply):

```
app.controller('Dashboard', ['$window', '$scope', '$http', function ($window, $scope, $http) {
    var url = new URL('/dashboard', window.location.href);
    url.protocol = url.protocol.replace('http', 'ws');
    var socket = new WebSocket(url.href);
    socket.onopen = function () {
        console.log("Status: Connected")
     };
    $scope.RX = function(event) {
        $scope.data = event.data
        $scope.$apply(); 
        console.log(event.data)
    };
    socket.onmessage = $scope.RX;
    console.log($scope.data)
}]);
```

AngularJS modifies the normal JavaScript flow by providing its own event processing loop. This splits the JavaScript into classical and AngularJS execution context. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc.

You can also use [$apply()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply) to enter the AngularJS execution context from JavaScript. Keep in mind that in most places (controllers, services) `$apply` has already been called for you by the directive which is handling the event. An explicit call to `$apply` is needed only when implementing custom event callbacks, or when working with third-party library callbacks.

For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Integration with the browser event loop](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope).

[image]

Comment: Hero! Working now!